# How to convert object into string using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a web app using PHP and MySQL.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="buttony">All</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="buttony1">Strength</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="buttony2">Agility</button>
             <?php echo "<a href='heroes/" . get_intelligence_hero($name) . ".html'" . "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' id='buttony3'>Intelligence</button>"; ?>
```

Using PHP it receives a random row from the database and then when you click it, it takes you to that row's own html page (It is for a game called DOTA2. You click what attribute the hero has and it will randomly choose a hero for you and take it to the webpage).

```
function get_intelligence_hero($name){
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM heroes WHERE attribute = 'intelligence' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    if(!$result) {
        die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $hero = serialize((mysqli_fetch_object($result)));

    echo $hero;
}
```

Here is my function for retrieving that hero if he is based on the Intelligence attribute. I used serialize to see if it would convert into a string. However it gives me this result:

```
O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Dazzle";}
```

So it did convert the row into a string as well as retrieved the hero. How do I get just the Row? For example, how do I just get "Dazzle" out of all of the text it returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the column you need:

```
...
$hero_object = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
$hero_name = $hero_object->name;

return $hero_name;
```

Note that you should add error handling to your database calls to catch situations like empty record sets, etc.

Also note that if you are going to use the variable in a url and in html output, you should escape it correctly. For example in your function to return a value you can use in your url:

```
return urlencode($hero_name);
```

You don't need `htmlspecialchars()` in this case as none of the special characters in html will remain un-encoded when you use `urlencode()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also love how you went into detail about the HTML encoding. Thank you very much.